# Keras Lambda layer: multiply a tensor with a matrix of constant

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, deep-learning

I'm writing a Lambda layer in Keras to compute the multiplication of a tensor and a matrix of constant. But the size went wrong in the output.

In the code, `jdes` is a tensor with dimension `TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(100)])`. Further, `six_title_embedding` is the matrix of constants and it has shape `(6, 100)`.

```
def cosine_distance(input):
    jd = K.l2_normalize(input, axis=-1)
    jt_six = K.l2_normalize(six_title_embedding, axis=-1)
    return jd * jt_six
distance = Lambda(cosine_distance, output_shape=(None, 6,100))(jdes)
result = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(distance)
```

In the output, I was expecting `result` to have shape `(None, 6, 1)` but now it's `(6, 1)` so the number of `batch_size` is lost during the computation of the lambda layer. The shape of `distance` is now `TensorShape([Dimension(6), Dimension(100)])`. Should this be `(None, 6, 100)` so that result can have `(None, 6, 1)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an additional axis for `jdes` so that when multiplying it with constant tensor, they could be broadcasted to the same shape:

```
def cosine_distance(input):
    jd = K.l2_normalize(input, axis=-1)
    jt_six = K.l2_normalize(six_title_embedding, axis=-1)
    jd = K.expand_dims(jd, axis=1)  # now it would have a shape of (None, 1, 100)
    return jd * jt_six  # the result would be (None, 6, 100)
```